# How to remove more than one element from a queue in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a queue as:

```
from Queue import Queue
myqueue = Queue()
```

How do I remove lets say 10 elements from the queue? I currently have the following:

```
for i in range(10):
    myqueue.get()
```

is there a beautiful way for this? Currently the dummy variable i is not being used, is there a way to avoid that from happening?

Comment: What do you mean by better way?

Comment: To expand on @thefourtheye's question, "Better" is a very subjective term. Do you mean objectively faster? Subjectively easier to read? More idiomatic?

Comment: And is this the `Queue.Queue` class or the `multiprocessing.Queue` class?

Comment: I meant more idiomatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no.

A queue is meant to be used for concurrent access (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html), where multiple workers fetch items from a single queue.

Simple example: your worker retrieves 10 items. On the first item, the worker crashes for some runtime error, say due to memory exhaustion or disk corruption. What happens to the remaining 9 items? Should they be put back in the queue for other workers to fetch them?

Could you elaborate a bit more on what you are trying to do, by fetching more than one item at the time? How many workers do you have? Why 10 and not 100? Etc.

Comment: I am using a simple queue in a single thread. Thank you pointing out the concurrent access thats useful to know.

Comment: @user1932405 if you're using a queue in a single thread, why not just use `list` as a queue? Intuitively I feel like it must be faster.

Comment: @user1932405: If you're only using a single thread, you should probably use a `deque` from the `collections` module, rather than a `Queue`. It has a somewhat more flexible API, but still doesn't have a way of dropping 10 items from the queue at a time.

Comment: Could you remove more than 10 items from a list at any one time? Seems like ive used the wrong data structure.

Comment: @user1932405 you could slice a list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation

Comment: Found the answer if I do queue.queue.clear() then that works, but must be careful that no one writes to that queue during that time. Therefore use the mutex of with queue.mutex: queue.queue.clear()